# Perturbation of a matrix with negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a square matrix with all eigenvalues negative. What is the relationship between the $\lambda_\max$ of perturbed matrix $A + X$ and the norm of the perturbation $\|X\|$?

PS: I know that the spectral radius of $A+X$ is bounded by the spectral radii of $A$ and $X$, but it only considers $\lambda$ with maximum absolute value, and in my case I'm worried about the sign of $\lambda_\max$.

Comment: Is the perturbation symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Given a (real symmetric) $n\times n$ matrix $A$, for each 
$k$, $1\le k\le n$, define the numbers
\begin{equation}
\lambda_k \,=\, \lambda_k(A) \,=\, \sup_{V_{k-1}}
\bigg( \inf_{\substack{
\boldsymbol{u}\perp V_{k-1} \\ \|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1}}
\langle\boldsymbol{u},A\boldsymbol{u}\rangle\bigg),\tag{1}
\end{equation} 
where the supremum is taken over all $(k-1)$-planes 
(i.e., $(k-1)$-dimensional subspaces) $V_{k-1}$. By convention
$V_0=\{0\}$ so $\lambda_1=\inf_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1}\langle\boldsymbol{u},A\boldsymbol{u}\rangle$.

**Theorem.** (Courant, Rayleigh & Ritz).
*The quantities $\lambda_k$, as defined
by $(1)$ are increasing
$$
\lambda_1 \,\le\, \lambda_2 \,\le\, \cdots \,\le\, \lambda_n,
$$
and are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$, with appropriate multiplicities.*

Hence
$$
|\lambda_{j}(A+X)-\lambda_{j}(A)|\le \max_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1}\langle\boldsymbol{u},X\boldsymbol{u}\rangle=\|X\|.
$$

All these, provided that the perturbation is symmetric!

Comment: Thanks, that's a totally cool theorem, but in my case A and X are jacobians and hessians, so they are not symmetric in general. I tested numerically and found that for some random matrices this relation is broken (although extremely rarely), probably because of the lack of symmetry. Is there any hope for general matrices?

Comment: A negative definite matrix is also symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I made a mistake in the statement of the question. I edited the question. The point is that matrix has all negative eigenvalues (a global stable fixed point)